# How to write a GET function in an abstract method? Java

Tags: java, methods, abstract

I have been asked to define an abstract method (`getCustomerDAO()`) as `CustomerDAO` is a class on its own. How do I set up this get function as when i write

```
abstract public void get.CustomerDAO();
```

the software provides an error stating

> '(' expected  invalid method declaration; return type expected.

Comment: Why dot between get and Customer?

Comment: try getting rid of the period in your method signature

Answer (score 2):

The dot in the method signature is making it invalid...

```
abstract public void get.CustomerDAO();
```

try instead something valid like:

```
abstract public void getCustomerDAO();
```

Comment: Thank you, after several hours sat infront of the ol laptop my brain is all over the shop. It was just the . thank you for the help